# JSF 2.0: How to override base renderers with custom ones?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to override renderer for `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` (for the reasons explained [here](http://www.i-coding.de/www/en/jsf/bug/selectbooleancheckbox-converter.html)):

However, I find it impossible to register my renderer. I have tried declaring it in my `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.SelectBoolean</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Checkbox</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.myapp.CustomCheckboxRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

The values I grabbed from:

- component-family: `javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox`
- renderer-type: `javax.faces.component.html.SelectBooleanCheckboxTag`

But it doesn't work.

I also tried verbosely declaring the `RenderKit`:

```
<description>Custom renderers</description>
<render-kit-id>???</render-kit-id>
<render-kit-class>com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl</render-kit-class>
```

But as you can see, I don't really know where to grab value for `render-kit-id` or if the `render-kit-class` is correct anyway.

Inside Mojarra package there is file `jsf-ri-runtime.xml` but it doesn't declare the renderers. It only declares a `RenderKitFactory`, under which I don't directly find anything of interest.

Pointers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your initial `<renderer>` declaration looks fine, so I tried it here.

```
package com.myapp;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CheckboxRenderer;

public class CustomCheckboxRenderer extends CheckboxRenderer {

    public CustomCheckboxRenderer() {
        System.out.println("CustomCheckboxRenderer <init>");
    }

    @Override
    public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
        System.out.println("CustomCheckboxRenderer decode()");
        super.decode(context, component);
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("CustomCheckboxRenderer encodeBegin()");
        super.encodeBegin(context, component);
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("CustomCheckboxRenderer encodeEnd()");
        super.encodeEnd(context, component);
    }

}
```

It works fine. All get printed to stdout. Your problem lies somewhere else. I was using Mojarra 2.0.3 on Tomcat 7.0.5.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, why would you ever use non-booleans as value of a `selectBooleanCheckbox`? How can a non-boolean object represent a boolean state?

Comment: Hmm, you are right, it does work. I didn't test with the encodeXXX methods before, I just set breakpoint to my custom renderer's  `getConvertedValue` method, which doesn't get called. The reason for that might be subject of a completely different question, however. Anyway, do you know if there is a listing for JSF components, their render-types and families somewhere, or do we have to always navigate to their classes and search for these variables?

Comment: It's a combination of table 8.1 in JSF 2.0 spec and the [`COMPONENT_FAMILY`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.component.UISelectBoolean.COMPONENT_FAMILY) constant field value in JSF 2.0 API doc. Eventually, chapter 4.1.x of JSF 2.0 spec can be consulted for both.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you once again! (although I fear this will not be the last time... :)

Answer (score 2):

I add renderers to my `faces-config.xml` like so:

```
<faces-config>
    <!--elided-->
<render-kit>
    <render-kit-id>HTML_BASIC</render-kit-id>
    <renderer>
        <display-name>MyRenderer</display-name>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>foo.MyRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>foo.MyRenderer</renderer-class>
        <!-- TODO: attributes for tooling -->
```

You don't need to (and shouldn't) declare a new render kit class in this scenario.

Comment: Does one need to declare the `render-kit-id` when overriding the default ones? Seems to work without it... does HTML_BASIC refer to "default" RenderKit?

Comment: @Tuukka Mustonen - render-kit-id is optional for the default RenderKit (there is an example in the spec). HTML_BASIC is indeed the default id.