# What's exactly is the difference between types of h:commandbutton?

Tags: html, jsf, button

Hi I have a question that I always want to ask. I'm talking about different types of `type` tag. I read about it a little, but most pages have only names of different tag and nothing more. what is the scope of such a CommandButton, `forms` ,maybe `tags`? Which the `textfields` are cleaned after use with the tag `reset` button?
Especially (if there are some differences with `HTML button`) i want to know about `JavaServer Faces` `commandButton.`

i'm looking for some advanced specification or something. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_commandButton.html?

Comment: I know this web page, did you read my post at all? It's just list the possible options without any explain. I'm looking for more detailed description, like documentation.

Comment: That's the documentation. What are you really looking for? There's no scope for the components nor the forms nor any of the tags, the scope is for the managed beans. Also, the `<h:commandLink>` will generate a `<button>` HTML (or whatever the [renderer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4605401/1065197) implementation specifies). In the end, JSF will just render HTML.

Comment: I am looking for a wider description of the different values that the `type` attribute ( `<h:commandButton type="reset" />` and so on )can have.

Comment: From the link: *type: The type attribute sets the type of button to create for this component (...) This attribute accepts the following values: reset, submit*.

Comment: If you really want to get so technical with JSF, you can read the specification of [JSF 2.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) or the upcoming [JSF 2.2](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=344) and find your answers there.

Comment: I'm looking for the description of what these values ​​do

Comment: jsf specification does not explain this

Answer (score 7):

The `<h:commandButton type="submit">` (default) generates a HTML `<input type="submit">` the `<h:commandButton type="reset">` generates a HTML `<input type="reset">` and the `<h:commandButton type="button">` generates a HTML `<input type="button">`.

That's all, really. That's also specified as such in [`<h:commandButton>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html). For the functional difference between the HTML representations, just look in [HTML forms spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html). Note that this part is completely beyond the scope of JSF.

After all, perhaps it's helpful if you learn [basic HTML](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/) before learning JSF as that's basically what JSF generates.