# Using a custom global filter on p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-datatable

I am trying to implement a comma separated keyword search using global filter in PrimeFaces.

If user types in `word1,word2` in the global search, all the rows which have `word1` and `word2` should be returned. As of now, I was not able to find a predefined multi word search functionality for global search in PrimeFaces. Global search only works with a single keyword. Eg: Search returns results only if user types either `word1` or `word2`.

Seems like PrimeFaces uses client API filter() for global search. Is there a way to implement a search using multiple keywords?

```
<p:dataTable id="dwg" widgetVar="tblDwgDtl" var="dwgDtl" 
 value="#{dwgCtrlr.dwgs} sortMode="multiple" scrollable="true" 
 styleClass="bsa-drawing" rows="25" resizableColumns="true">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:panelGrid styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="6">
                        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                        onkeyup="PF('tblDwgDtl').filter()" 
                        placeholder="#{msg['searchAllFields.text']}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
   </f:facet>
```

Answer (score 6):

### PrimeFaces 8.0 and up

From PrimeFaces 8.0 you can use the `globalFilterFunction` attribute of the `p:dataTable` to implement your custom global filter. See 
https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datatable?id=filtering

Example use:

```
<p:dataTable ... globalFilterFunction="#{dtFilterView.globalFilterFunction}">
  ...
</p:dataTable>
```

```
public boolean globalFilterFunction(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
  String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
  if (filterText == null || filterText.equals("")) {
    return true;
  }
  int filterInt = getInteger(filterText);

  Car car = (Car) value;
  return car.getId().toLowerCase().contains(filterText)
          || car.getBrand().toLowerCase().contains(filterText)
          || car.getColor().toLowerCase().contains(filterText)
          || (car.isSold() ? "sold" : "sale").contains(filterText)
          || car.getYear() < filterInt
          || car.getPrice() < filterInt;
}
```

In your case of multiple words:

```
public boolean globalFilterFunction(Object rowValue, Object filter, Locale locale) {
  String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString();
  if (filterText == null || filterText.isEmpty()) {
    return true;
  }
  return Stream.of(filterText.split(","))
          .allMatch(word -> singleWordFilter(value, word));
}

private boolean singleWordFilter(Object rowValue, String word) {
  // do your single word filtering logic
}
```

### Before PrimeFaces 8.0

What you could do is [replace the data table renderer with a custom one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605401/jsf-2-0-how-to-override-base-renderers-with-custom-ones). Then, [in there](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/de8d458d6f33605fe9044e590b91a365e2d9139f/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java#L155), replace the `FilterFeature` with a custom version. So, you would need extend the `FilterFeature` and [take care of the multiple keywords there](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/73849a3f070692deb7459d01c0ca8d5b15cdc1ac/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/feature/FilterFeature.java#L204).